# Incorrect single precision floating point representation on ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: c, ubuntu, floating-point, 64-bit, ieee-754

I have the following data.

```
float u[4] = {0x3f951d32, 0x3f207887, 0x3d99c3a0, 0x3eb405d2};
ScaleFunction(u);

void ScaleFunction(float *u_ptr)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    printf("u[%d] = %f\n", u_ptr[i]);
  }
  // And a lot more
}
```

The application containing the snippet above is executed on a 64 bit machine running ubuntu 16.10.

Much to my chagrin, the floating point numbers are incorrectly interpreted as: 1066736960.000000, 1059092608.000000, 1033487232.000000 and 1051985344.000000.

The numbers when printed in hexadecimal confirm that the caller passes the correct values to callee.

What am I doing wrong here?

I even tried the following with no joy.

```
uint32_t u[4] = {0x3f951d32, 0x3f207887, 0x3d99c3a0, 0x3eb405d2};
ScaleFunction(u);

void ScaleFunction(uint32_t *u_ptr)
{
  float ut[4];
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    ut[i] = (float) u_ptr[i];
    printf("ut[%d] = %f\n", ut[i]);
  }
  // And a lot more
}
```

I expect to interpret the hexadecimals in the callee as:
    1.1649, 0.6268, 0.075, 0.5516

Comment: "What are you _doing_ wrong?" — nothing.  It's your expectations that seem to be askew.  You initialized the `float` array to a series of integer values, and you see those values printed, and seem to be surprised by this result.  What result are you after?  (Also, you should provide an actual MCVE — [MCVE] — to ensure you show the real code.)

Comment: `printf("u[%d] = %f\n", u_ptr[i]);` Undefined behavior here?

Comment: Just for anyone else wondering the first hex integer in decimal is 1066736946

Comment: `printf("u[%d] = %f\n" u_ptr[i]);` ---> `printf("u[%d] = %f\n", i, u_ptr[i]);`

Comment: The second code contains a cast (which could be omitted without changing the result) that converts the integer value to the corresponding `float`.  If you're looking to copy the bits from the integer to the `float`, you need to handle that differently — it gets messy around there, because you aren't encouraged to do it.  You could try a union: `union { float f; uint32_t u; } v;` and then assign the integer to `v.u` and print `v.f`, but that's technically undefined behaviour.

Comment: Float might not have the "precision" or "range" to show integer values in that range. Check the sizes. For example a 32bit float has no way of storing a 32bit integer, with bits in the highest byte and lowest byte set.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what your init really does: it is assigning integers to float, not directly its hex float representation.

Comment: If you want hexadecimal floating point values, then I suggest you read e.g. [this floating point constant reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is using Unions to cast bits really UB? I thought that was the standard way for type punning?

Comment: Shouldn't the hexadecimals be interpreted as a IEEE 754 formatted number especially given the fact that my desired data type is a float?

Comment: No; the hexadecimals will not be interpreted as an IEEE 754 formatted number.  You'd have to use the hexadecimal floating point format suggested by others.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Yes, it is undefined behaviour, but yes, it is also the way it is generally done.  I'm not going to quote the standard, but the information is there in the standard.

Comment: @Raj Please [edit] your question and **give an example of value you are expecting**. I am guessing you want to reinterpret bits of unsigned type as float type without numeric conversion, but it's impossible to know unless you clarify.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are you thinking of C++ or C89? Union type punning was allowed in C99.

Comment: In C11, footnote 95 in §6.7.2.1 **Structure and union specifiers** says: _If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
punning’’). This might be a trap representation._ You're right, @user694733, that C11 (and presumably C99; I've not checked) makes it legal but a little precarious. It's iffy, but you'll usually get away with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you initialize your array with large integer values, not the hex representation of the floats. With your hex constants starting with values around 0x3f it's pretty clear that these are floating point data with values around 1.0.

As far as I know there is no direct way to initialize a float array with hex constants (if there is one, community, please tell me!).

So you have to define your data-array as int and convert it to float as you use it. **IMPORTANT:** Directly casting the pointer from int to float will break the aliasing rule of C and may result in code that looks correct but misbehaves.

Converting between the two data-types via memcpy is safe though and the compiler is usually smart enough to spot this and optimize it out.

So this solution here does what you want:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t u[4] = {0x3f951d32, 0x3f207887, 0x3d99c3a0, 0x3eb405d2};

void ScaleFunction(uint32_t *u_ptr)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
      float temp;
      memcpy (&temp, &u[i], sizeof (float));
      printf("u[%d] = %f\n", i, temp);
  }
  // And a lot more
}


void main (int argc, char **args)
{
  ScaleFunction (u);
}
```

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck ...and where do you ensure `sizeof(float == sizeof(uint32_t)`.....;)

Comment: @LPs float is defined as 32 bit in the IEEE 754 floating-point standard.

Comment: The standard does not say anything about float and double size. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You code cannot work as you think: you are assigning integers to your float. You are not assigning the HEX values as float.

Best thing you can do is to have a init array and copy it to your `float` array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

uint32_t init[] = {0x3f951d32u, 0x3f207887u, 0x3d99c3a0u, 0x3eb405d2u};

void ScaleFunction(float *u_ptr, size_t size)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("u[%zu] = %f\n", i, u_ptr[i]);
  }
  // And a lot more
}

int main (void)
{
    assert ( sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t) );

    float u[sizeof(init)/sizeof(init[0])];

    memcpy(u, init, sizeof(init));

    ScaleFunction(u, sizeof(init)/sizeof(init[0]));
}
```